# Android Studio for Windows is not installing and updating packages

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run the Android SDK Manager and I try to install or update it fails and I can't install anything.

How can I do to install or update new packages?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the "log window" to get more information about the problem. There is a icon in the bottom left of the SDK Manager to access to the log.

Anyway, the most usual problem is that you probably are not running Android Studio as administrator so it can't create new folders. Try to run Android Studio as administrator and it should work.